# Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Tags: perl, excel, win32ole, vba

How can I convert the following excel vba statement to perl win32::ole statement?

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

I've converted as follows, but doesn't work:

```
my $Excel = CreateObject OLE "Excel.Application";
my $SecondSht = $Book->ActiveSheet;
$SecondSht->Range("P2")->Select();
$SecondSht->Range({$Excel->Selection(), {$Excel->Selection()->End({xlDown})})->Select(); #fails at this statement
$Excel->Selection->Copy;
$SecondSht->Range({"Q2"})->Select;
$SecondSht->Paste;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer!

```
$SecondSht->Range($SecondSht->Range("P2"), $SecondSht->Range("P2")->End(xlDown))->Select();
$Excel->Selection->Copy;
$SecondSht->Range("Q2")->Select();
$SecondSht->Paste;
```